# 期末. can this be translated as "Balance sheet date"?

Tags: meaning, translation

> 役員退職慰労引当金……役員の退職慰労金の支給に備えるため、内規に基づく 期末要支給額を計上しております。

My understanding: Provision for retirement benefits for officers... In order to prepare for the payment of retirement benefits for officers, the company recognizes the amount required to be paid at the end of the period in accordance with the internal regulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think 「期末{きまつ}」 in finance means the end of an accounting year or accounting period. 「期末要支給額」is a fixed finance term that means "accrued benefits at the end of year." As per this [EY Japan (accounting firm) page](https://www.shinnihon.or.jp/corporate-accounting/glossary/retirement-benefits/kimatu-you-sikyugaku.html):

> 期末要支給額とは、期末現在において全従業員が退職すると仮定した場合に、会社の退職金規程等に基づいて計算した、全従業員に対する退職金の支給総額をいいます。一般的に、退職金規程等に基づいて計算される退職金の額は、自己の都合による退職なのか、会社の都合による退職なのかにより金額が異なるため、それぞれ、自己都合期末要支給額と会社都合期末要支給額とが計算できます。

The 「期」in「期末」refers to an [accounting period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accounting_period)/[会計期間{かいけいきかん}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BC%9A%E8%A8%88%E6%9C%9F%E9%96%93) which is usually a year. Thus, 「期末」refers to the end of that period.